# Edge makes my screen go bonkers when Firefox is running

Tags: firefox, windows-11, microsoft-edge

I usually use Mozilla Firefox as a browser, but there is a user interface for an events calendar that doesn't work right with it, so I tried to do that in Microsoft Edge instead. The problem is that when I start Edge, my full screen fills up with snow. It settles down after a few seconds, but then it does haywire again when I move the cursor.

I am able to close Edge eventually by waiting out those periods of chaos until I can click on the "X" to close Edge. But then, it still isn't entirely over because any text showing on the screen -- in menus, Word, or whatever, has pixels that move around and make it blurry. I have to re-boot to get back to normal.

Has anybody else had this experience?

FYI I am running Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.2.22621 Build 22621, and Mozilla Firefox 110.0.1 (64-bit). (I don't dare try to find out what Edge version I have.) It also seems like it may be relevant to mention I have Firefoix add-ins such as Adblock Plus.

Comment: Though I've not had that particular issue, many browsers use immense amounts of resources, as do browser-based applications, such as Zoom client, which can greatly slow a PC. You might have insufficient RAM or video RAM to run both browsers simultaneously. BTW, try another browser, such as Brave, to see if it cooperates better with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously, trying a different browser promises to help. I had tried Edge because I didn't have chrome and I have an attitude about Google. I'll look into Brave.

Comment: Yes, Brave *promises* a bit more privacy than MS or Google (or their browser) do. BTW, if you want to forgo the Brave online installer, and would rather download the files and unzip into folder of your choice, see https://techviral.net/download-brave-browser/ for offline installation files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know more about this now...

I stopped using Mozilla Firefox and started using Brave. But at some point, Brave started doing the same thing...

- Changing the display resolution seemed to keep it from happening. That may just be luck.
- As before, the chaos seemed to be associated with mouse movements. I can't be sure, but I think it was also associated with the Windows 11 feature|annoyance of wanting to snap windows to a choice of layouts when dragging a window towards the top of the screen. I later found out I could disable this feature; good riddance.
- In the Brave profile, I disabled using hardware acceleration. That seems to have prevented it. (I did this before disabling the snap-layout stuff, so am not sure of snap-layout's role, if any)